# Взять id кнопки из формы с помощью ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Есть форма:

```html
<form method="POST">
  <input type="submit" class="sub" id="123" value="Кнопка">
</form>
```

Мне нужно взять id кнопки и потом использовать этот id в php.

Comment: либо замените `value` на это значение, либо добавьте `hidden` поле с этим значением

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Используйте атрибут name при сабмите он передается на сервер.

Comment: Вообще, судя по тегу `ajax` можно предположить что автору нужен именно он.. Тогда не нужны никакие ни `value`, ни скрытые `input`'ы...

Answer (score 0):

[Скрытое поле | htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml5/formy/skrytoe-pole)

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="submit" class="sub" id="123" value="Кнопка">
  <input type="hidden" name="id_button" value="123">
</form>
```

Comment: А самой кнопке нельзя задать `name` с тем же `id`?

Comment: @InDevX, по идее можно. Но есть у тебя куча форм, а обработчик один, то думаю лучше будет через hidden